# I have a small issue with drawingin Javascript Graphics 2D

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics2d

Just for fun and learning, I am trying to create a web based forms editor in the manner of Visual Studio. First requirement is the ability to draw a rectangle so that the outline follows the mouse movement while drawing. So with every mouse displacement, the previously drawn rectangle should be wiped. To achieve this, before drawing a new rectangle, I restore a snapshot of the canvas that was taken when the mouse button was pressed down.

This works well enough, the flickering is understandable but not too disturbing as long as I keep some continuous movement in the mouse. But what I fail to understand, and what is really annoying, is that the rectangle disappears as soon as I stop the mouse movement for more than a split second.
I put a minimal test set in this Codepen [https://codepen.io/cbreemer/pen/mdgOQdQ] so the issue will be clear even is maybe my explanation wasn't.

I am hoping somebody can tell me what I am missing here.

I thought that maybe moving the rectangle-drawing code inside the image load handler (in the mouse move handler) might fix it. But sadly, then I don't see anything until the mouse button is released. I can't think of anything else to try.

```js
    var ctx;
    var startX, startY, endX, endY, lastX, lastY;
    var rect;
    var lastCanvas;
    var isMouseDown = false;

    function init()
    {
        rect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillStyle = "wheat";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);

        myCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(e)=>
        {
            if ( isMouseDown )
            {
                var canvasPic = new Image();
                canvasPic.src = lastCanvas;
                canvasPic.addEventListener("load", (e)=> { ctx.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0); });

                var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
                var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
                ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, x-startX, y-startY);
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
            }
        });

        myCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>
        {
            lastCanvas = myCanvas.toDataURL();
            startX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            startY = e.clientY - rect.top;
            lastX  = startX;
            lastY  = startY;
            isMouseDown = true;
        });

        myCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup",(e)=>
        {
            isMouseDown = false;
            endX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            endY = e.clientY - rect.top;
            ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY);
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad="init();">
<canvas id="myCanvas"  width="600" height="400" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider using a snippet (the `<>` button)?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, a very clean solution would be to keep the rectangles coordinates in an array and redraw all every time. In the current situation you have to redraw the last rectangle on mousemove after you replace the image, not only on mouseup

Comment: Thanks guys, I am new here and still struggling to find the proper way to include code and I see my post has already been edited. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: I can only guess that this is probably due to the not very sophisticated method for restoring previous canvas contents, that you have chosen here. Creating a data URI of the whole canvas content, that then needs to be parsed and drawn onto the canvas again - that probably takes too much time, I'm guessing. Canvas already comes with a "Stack" implementation that you can use to restore previous states - so try and implement that part using those methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#the_canvas_state

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Thanks for your reply ! Much appreciated. Although I'm not sure what exactly you mean with "redraw all every time". You mean keeping the coordinates of all the already completed rectangles, so that I can repaint them on each mouse move ? Seems like an option but how would that be better/cleaner than restoring the last canvas image ?
As to your second sentence, isn't that exactly what I am already doing ? Could me I am just missing the point.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the feedback ! I got the idea from a page where someone had implemented an Undo/Redo feature this way. Your message filled me with joy as it looked like I could do indeed implement this in a much better way. But reading this man page, it seems like that stack only holds drawing style states, not the actual graphics contents. You think it is worth trying it out anyway ?

Comment: AFK right now and it's quite hard to see why you need drawImage at all, but note that you can draw a canvas synchronously with drawImage, even over itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taken from another answer of mine, Here's the basic idea of redrawing the canvas every tick of the `requestAnimationFrame`.
It also demonstrated how to better redraw image (taken using `getImageData`.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector(".result");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Loading of the home test image - img1
var img1 = new Image();
var imageData

//drawing of the test image - img1
img1.onload = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawRect()

};

img1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img1.src = 'https://picsum.photos/400/200';


function drawRect() {
  let SldrVal = document.getElementById("MySldr").value;
  //ctx.strokeStyle = "#305ef2";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);


  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, SldrVal, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.font = "32px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(SldrVal, 10, 50);

  requestAnimationFrame(drawRect)
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="MySldr" value="15" min="1" max="100">
<br>
<canvas class="result" width="400" height="160"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why would using getImageData be any better?

Comment: faster than `toDataURL()`? i haven't tested it but i'm pretty sure it would be, not having to encode as base64 string

Comment: That's not what's slow about toDataURL. The slowness comes from the fact the bitmap on the GPU has to be moved to the CPU, and then back again on the GPU. The different contexts have to wait for each other which is terrible in an animation. But that's true for both getImageData and toDataURL, so it's not better but  just as bad. (Well it might be abit better because it's synchronous whereas the loading of the image isn't, but it's still very bad)

Comment: ok might as well. but why is that bad? what is the alternative for redrawing the canvas as a universal solution?

Comment: Draw the canvas directly, `drawImage` accepts `<canvas>` as source

Comment: Wow, so many helpful comments ! It was the example provided by @ITgoldman that nailed it. When analyzing this I discovered that all I needed was to use getImageData() and putImageData() instead of toDataURL(). My code was correct apart from that. I did not even have to use requestAnimationFrame().
So, it works beautifully now !  Many thanks guys. I'll see how I can mark this issue solved (still grop;ing around a bit on this great but somewhat bewildering site).